# Associated Tensors.

Tags: vectors, tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank

I came across this question which asked us to come up with the "second order antisymmetric tensor *associated* with a vector" which was given in the problem. The components of the vector were coordinate dependent and the problem was to be solved in Cartesian coordinates. What I can't understand (and I can't find it anywhere) is what is meant by a tensor associated with a vector? What does the word *associated* imply here?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a bit more context on this? I found something that might be useful:

http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~ceng501/Chap2.pdf

Look at "The vector of an antisymmetric tensor", but I'm not sure how well it would work for your application

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that might be useful:

http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~ceng501/Chap2.pdf

Look at "The vector of an antisymmetric tensor".

It appears to be a way to take the fact that in three dimensions an anti-symmetric tensor can be related to a vector. \begin{equation}\Omega_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk} \omega_k\end{equation}

Comment: Just as a side comment: this is a particular instance of the notion of Hodge star. Assuming one has an oriented Euclidean vector space $(V,g)$, one has the notion of Hodge star, which is a (family of) isometry(s) $\star$ between $\Lambda^k V$ and $\Lambda^n-k V$, where $n=\dim V$.

In particular, for $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, the correspondence is given by
$$ V \simeq_{g} V^* \simeq_{\star} \Lambda^{3-1} V^*$$
where the last term is to be seen as the skew-symmetric 2-tensors. $V\simeq V^*$ is the isom induced by $g$.

These linear constructions carry over to sections of vector bundles.